# how to remove or delete other meshlab plugin functions from source code?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, meshlab, cmake-gui

I have imported QT5 C++ project from GitHub [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5rFk.png) of MeshLab plugin and many of the plugin functions I have already deleted and other I want to delete from application so how to remove these functions from source code. I just want open project option and nothing else. So when I import mesh and the file display on application display. How can i remove these plugins?

I have deleted many files from meshlabplugins file. I can't understand other things what to do. When I am commenting or delete something output shows errors here's my [screenshot of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0IJ6.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You will need to at least tell us the URL of this GitHub repo. It's not very efficient or good etiquette to expect others to find information that you could easily provide. Please help us help you!

Comment: Also, I anticipate that you may find yourself waiting a while for an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers. While I'm not sure if this _question_ counts as being too broad, I imagine (without knowing anything about the code you are referring to) an answer to this question could be quite lengthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gui of the main window is created in MainWindow::createActions()

I would suggest to comment code that create actions and menu that you don't need.